# How to get the vaue of each line on textarea using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hope you could help me out of this loop.. It loops and get all text wen hit enter. Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#referencecode').keypress(function(event) {
        var lines = $('#referencecode').val().split('\n');
        var getdata;
        
        if (event.which == 13 ) {
            for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
            //code here using lines[i] which will give you each line
                getdata = lines[i];
            }
            alert('Line ' + i + ' is ' + getdata);
        }
    });
    
    $('#referencecode').on("paste",function(event) {
        
        setTimeout(function () {
            var lines = $('#referencecode').val().split('\n');
            var getdata;
            for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
                getdata = lines[i];
                alert('Line ' + i + ' is ' + getdata);
            }
        },100); 
        
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="referencecode" placeholder="input data here"></textarea>
<textarea id="checkcode" placeholder="input data here"></textarea>
```

Expecting Results:

1. A result that will check each line when user hit enter and append to another textarea for checking. Let's say data1 is valid if it has value. Example:

   [data1] --> enter --> [data1 valid]
   [data2] --> enter --> [data2 invalid]
   [data3] --> enter --> [data2 valid]
2. When user paste a set of text with a newline:

   [data1
   data2
   data3]
   -->
   [data1 valid
   data2 invalid
   data3 valid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var k =1;

var outdata = [];

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#referencecode').on("keypress", function(event) {

    if (event.which == 13) {
      var lines = $('#referencecode').val().split('\n');
      var validate = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        
         if(k == 1 || validate.length > 0){
            if(lines[i] != ''){
              validate.push(lines[i] +' Valid '); 
            }else{
              validate.push(lines[i] +' Invalid '); 
            }
            k++;
           }else{
              if(lines[lines.length-1] != ''){
               outdata.push('Line ' + (lines.length) + ' is ' + lines[lines.length-1]+ ' Valid');
             }else{
                outdata.push('Line ' + (lines.length) + ' is ' + lines[lines.length-1]+ ' Invalid');
               }
              $('#checkcode').val(outdata.join('\n'));
              return;
          }
       }
      if(validate.length > 0){
          outdata.push('Line ' + 1 + ' is ' + validate.join(','));
          $('#checkcode').val('Line ' + 1 + ' is ' + validate.join(','));
      }
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <textarea id="referencecode" placeholder="input data here"></textarea>
  <textarea id="checkcode" placeholder="input data here"></textarea>
```

Comment: sorry brother I updated the scenario. by the way, thank you

Comment: No problem anyway nice scenario made me to use my brain after sleep as a good warm up.

Comment: Thank you brother, try to shake you up this morning with some problem :)

Comment: oh still you need me to use my brain . anyway ill try it out.

Comment: Yes sir :) but first take a cup of coffee

Comment: Checkout the functionality

Comment: that's quick! I'm able to construct the code with my needs. Is it possible instead of alert it will push it to another textarea with the same line validation?

Comment: Check it out with display on second textarea

Comment: Wow! thank you sir! it work! 1 more thing would it possible to place it on same line without removing the other value?\

Comment: Just push to array and display it out will work fine

Comment: How that is possible? :)

Comment: Thank you sir! Will work on your great script now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231776/discussion-between-nithin-balasubramanian-and-mrrsb).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkedLines = [];

  $('#textcode').on("keypress", function(event) {

    if (event.which == 13) {
      var startPosition = document.getElementById('textcode').selectionStart;
      var endPosition = document.getElementById('textcode').selectionEnd;
      
      var lines = $('#textcode').val().split('\n');
      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        //code here using lines[i] which will give you each line
       if (checkedLines.filter(line => line === lines[i]).length === 0) {
        alert('Line ' + i + ' is ' + lines[i]);
        checkedLines.push(lines[i]);
       }
      }
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textcode" placeholder="input code here"></textarea>
```

You have to save all the checked lines in an array inside the ready() function. If the user hits the next time enter you just need to find the newly added lines and check them.

The only problem with this approach is that it won't work if you have two lines which contain the same text. In this case you could track which lines have been added by evaluating the cursor position with the selectionStart and selectionEnd. Another problem might occur if the user removes lines. In order to resolve this problem you might have to write a comparer which always (on every text change) checks the difference between old and new text and detect if a line was added or deleted.

Comment: sorry brother I updated the scenario. by the way, I consider some edits to work this on my script. thank you

Comment: I like this idea sir! Do you have sample code snippet? :)